# Reverse Engineering BIOS (AMI A0.57)

Tags: firmware, radare2, spi, bios, uefi

Recently I got really interested in BIOS RE and I used ***chipsec*** to dump the content of SPI Flash ROM of my **HP Omen** Desktop PC to start my journey. But unlike older BIOSes, the binary file was pretty huge (8.4 MB).

The bios image is **AMI A0.57 rev A**

I have a couple of problems with this BIOS image:

1. I can't disassemble it correctly. Using ***radare2*** with *-b flag*, I tried 16,32 and 64 but the file doesn't get disassembled correctly.
2. Using ***UEFI Tool***, it fails at parsing it correctly.
3. I googled and google and google. There no resource to solve my problem.
4. ***IDA Pro*** also treats the file as BIOS Image and uses one of its plugins ***bios_image.py*** to analyze the file but fails at some point with an error: Cannot relocate segment something at something (some addresses) because it overlap another segment.

Then I thought maybe Chipsec has failed with dumping the SPI Flash and the file is corrupted but I downloaded the BIOS image from HP's website (ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp81501-82000/sp81781.exe) and the file is the exact same. So, I have no clue and I need help to start learning BIOS reverse engineering.

P.S. I have read BIOS Disassembly Ninjutsu Uncovered; and I can provide the binary if necessary.

Please be **as specific as possible** in your answer since I googled 100 times and I'm really disappointed.
Thanks!

Comment: @SYS_V after downloading the executable, run it, there is an option which you can write the raw binary to a file.

Comment: BIOS are encrypted nowadays....it will be much more work than feeding it raw to a disassembler.

Answer (score 1):

After extracting the ROM image from the update, UEFITool parses it fine for me:

[image: UEFITool screenshot]

Comment: This parsing seems corrupted in my opinion. If you open each node, you will see they're all padding or empty. It makes no sense. Don't you agree? Or am I missing something?

Comment: There are enough valid modules so it's fine.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky where is the legacy bios stored before it's shadowed to 0xF0000? It doesn't appear to be in the SPI flash bios region. I thought it might be on the LPC flash but my laptop doesn't appear to have one, plus it looks like you can only send all bios accesses to either LPC or SPI on the chipset and not 0xF0000 to one and 0xFFFF0000 to another. I can't find _anything_ on this. My laptop is booted into legacy bios and has EA at 0xFFFF0 and 90 90 E9 at 0xFFFFFFF0

Comment: @LewisKelsey by “legacy bios” do you mean the 16-bit reset code, or the CSM for legacy OS? You might want to create a new question with more details.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Yes, the 16 bit reset code that jumps to the POST entry point at F000:E05B